# How do I force <a> links to open in a new tab on a constantly updating web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to force `<a>` links on my webpage to open in a new tab. I have tried using this code:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
});
```

But it simply doesn't work. I guess this could be because the content is updated after the page is fully loaded due to some kind of scripting, but I have tried rechecking every second for new links so I doubt it. Here is the relevant code:

```js
function checkForNewLinks() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Initial check on page load
  checkForNewLinks();

  // Check for new links every second
  setInterval(checkForNewLinks, 1000);
});
```

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: You can use a `MutationObserver` to detect when new links are added and update them.

Comment: If it's YOUR web page, why don't you just fix the HTML to do what you want?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. If I run in in devtools, on this StackOverflow page, I can see the DOM update to include the newly added `target` attributes. Given the fact that you're re-executing every 1s (which is terrible for performance BTW), I can't imagine that it's an issue of elements not being ready when your script fires off.

Comment: by chance, are your links loading in an iframe?

Comment: @josh yes It is in an iframe

Comment: In that case, assuming the iframe content is on the same domain, you probably need to update your `links` variable to take the iframe into account. Something like `document.getElementById(iframeID).contentWindow.document.document.getElementsByTagName('a');`

Comment: If the iframe is on a different domain or subdomain, then it won't be possible to directly manipulate due to security restrictions enforced by the Same-Origin Policy (SOP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the following code doesn't solve your issue, it should give you a starting point for debugging it more effectively:

```js
(() => {
  const modified = new WeakSet();
  const separator = '-'.repeat(40);
  let cycle = 0;
  
  function checkForNewLinks() {
    const allLinks = [...document.getElementsByTagName('a')];
    const virginLinks = allLinks.filter((link) => !modified.has(link));
    const linkCount = virginLinks.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < linkCount; i++) {
      const link = virginLinks[i];
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      modified.add(link);
    }
    console.debug(`Cycle ${++cycle}\n  Total Links: ${allLinks.length}\n  Newly Modified Links: ${linkCount}\n${separator}`);
    setTimeout(checkForNewLinks, 1000);
  }
  
  if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
    checkForNewLinks();
  } else {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkForNewLinks());
  }
})();
```

This uses a WeakSet to track previously modified links and outputs stats on each cycle.  As far as your code is concerned, it looks fine and appears to work on the few pages I tested it on.

There are several failure points that could be affecting you at runtime based on the environment:

- Usage in a worker
- Usage in an iframe element
- Usage in a content script
- Usage on a page with polluted or overridden native prototypes

Comment: alright i am trying in rn ill tell u if it works

Comment: s it didnt seem to work, so i just gave up and made it a button that opens in a new tab lol

Comment: now how do i close this lol

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cashe. If that doesn't work, use `MutationObserver`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).